# fetch data to display in ng-options but set dynamic default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

A user object is available to the view which populates a form. One of the elements to display information is a drop-down. Two requests are made. One for the `user information`, and the other for a list of `timezones`. Both are resolved through a `ui-router` state like so:

```
.state('app.userprofile', {
        url: '/userprofile',
        component: 'user',
        resolve: {
            user: ['userService', function(userService) {
                return userService.fetchUser();
            }],
            timezones: ['timezoneService', function(timezoneService){
                return timezoneService.fetchUsaTimeZones();
            }]
        }
    })
}]);
```

I have given a read of an [article](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/) I found online after the `select` element failed to populate with the users timezone, but the select element still fails to display information.

***Question***

How do I populate the default select option with data from the user `object` but populate the options from the second response.

```
<label for="timezones">Time Zone</label>
    <div>
        <select name="timezones"
            ng-init="userTimezone = $ctrl.user.business.timezone"
            ng-change="userTimezone = userTimezone.abbr"
            ng-model="userTimezone" 
            ng-options="item as item.abbr for item in $ctrl.timezones track by item.abbr" class="form-control">
            <option value="">{{userTimezone}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>{{userTimezone}}</p>
    </div>


//SECOND REQUEST FOR TIMEZONES
app.factory('timezoneService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var factory = {};

    factory.fetchUsaTimeZones = function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('../../p3sweb/assets/json/ustimezones.json')
        .then(
            function(response){
                console.log(response.data.ustimezones)
                deferred.resolve(response.data.ustimezones)
            },
            function(errResponse){
                deferred.resolve(errResponse)
            }
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return factory;

}])
```

---

```
{
  "ustimezones": [
  {
    "value": "Hawaiian Standard Time",
    "abbr": "HST",
    "offset": -10,
    "isdst": false,
    "text": "(UTC-10:00) Hawaii",
    "utc": [
      "Etc/GMT+10",
      "Pacific/Honolulu",
      "Pacific/Johnston",
      "Pacific/Rarotonga",
      "Pacific/Tahiti"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "Alaskan Standard Time",
    "abbr": "AKDT",
    "offset": -8,
    "isdst": true,
    "text": "(UTC-09:00) Alaska",
    "utc": [
      "America/Anchorage",
      "America/Juneau",
      "America/Nome",
      "America/Sitka",
      "America/Yakutat"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

It was throwing an error when I had the value of `ng-model` as `$ctrl.user.business.timezone` so I have stored the it in a variable `userTimezone` through the `ng-init` directive. Updated the code

**UPDATE 2**

I have it semi-working. It updates all fields though it throws an inconsitent 405 error. Not going to lie, I'm in one of those 'how the hell is this working' situations.

```
<select name="timezones"
    ng-init="userTimezone._abbr = {abbr: $ctrl.user.business.timezone}"
    ng-change="$ctrl.user.business.timezone = userTimezone._abbr"
    ng-model="userTimezone._abbr" 
    ng-options="zone.abbr as zone.text for zone in $ctrl.timezones track by zone.abbr" class="form-control">
<option value="">{{userTimezone._abbr}}</option>
</select>
<p>{{userTimezone._abbr}}</p>
```

Comment: Where are you initializing default select value?

Comment: I am just using {{}} expression and adding it to the option value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have complex objects as your options. Angular does equality comparison when checking the default value (which is set via the `ng-model` attribute), so with objects it's comparing object references (via the generated `$$hashkey` property). Because you have two different object references, once from the timezone list, once from the user, their hashkeys are different. Thus, they're treated as "not equal", so no default gets set.

If you extend your `ng-options` attribute to use `track by`, you can select a unique, primitive property where equality comparison makes more sense (such as the abbreviation). Angular will then use this property for equality/uniqueness comparison instead of the hashkey.

So you'd have something like

```
<select name="timezones" ng-model="$ctrl.user.business.timezone" ng-options="item as item.abbr for item in $ctrl.timezones track by item.abbr"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Still the `select` element doesn't display the users timezone as default and now I have a 400 error response

Comment: I don't see how the 400 error would be related to changing the template, so you may need make a working plunkr. As for the default, what is the value that you're storing in $ctrl.user.business.timezone? ngOptions applies the same track by property to the ngModel, so they need to have the same properties to get matched correctly. Working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FGFkSaf3bpFT0HYTnncU

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply.  The 400 error was my issue. That is solved, submitting data, all other fields are updating, apart from the data from the select :/